# MySQL deducing fields dynamically

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I'm trying to deduce a value in a `select` statement, then reuse that calculation a few times per row, as well as `group by` that value. In my case, I'm doing `time_to_sec(timediff(created, lastHit))` a bunch of times:

```
select
     time_to_sec(timediff(created, lastHit)) diff
    , if(
         time_to_sec(timediff(created, lastHit)) > 1800
         OR time_to_sec(timediff(created, lastHit)) = 0,
         1, 0
      ) newSession
    , sum(1) as sessions
    , sum(
          if(
             time_to_sec(timediff(created, lastHit)) > 1800, 
             0, time_to_sec(timediff(created, lastHit))
          )
      ) as totalDuration
    from pageviews
    group by newSession;
```

How can I improve that query without storing redundant data in my schema (such as the pre-calculated time difference between `created` and `lastHit`)?

I thought about using variables (`select @diff := timediff(...)`), but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715504/mysql-define-a-variable-within-select-and-use-it-within-the-same-select) mentions that I should avoid assigning a variable and reading from it within the same statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most situations, the recalculation of an expression is much less of a performance burden than any solution.  So, don't worry about it.

You have another issue -- The `GROUP BY` does not include the first thing in the `SELECT`, so the value you will get for that is unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the recalculation cost. Can you explain what you mean by the unpredictable value in my `GROUP BY`, please?

Comment: Say you have two tuples (x,y,z) = {(1,2,1), (1,3,2)}. What should the result of: `select x,y,sum(z) from T group by x` be? 1,2,3 or 1,3,3? This indeterminism is because y is not functionally dependent of x (and that MySQL allows partial group by). It is not obvious (for me at least), whether your select clause is functionally dependent of newSession or not. If not, you may end up with unpredictable results.